# Fetching LDAP attribute memberof inside Grails Spring application

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I am stuck possibly at a very stupid question, trying to implement LDAP role based authentication/authorization in a Grails application (bookstore) using spring-security-core and spring-security-ldap plugins. I created a custom UserDetailsContextMapper and trying to map my LDAP role with application role. However, the *memberof* attribute is never returned in the attributes.

```
UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username,
                                  Collection authorities) { 
        Attributes attributes = ctx.getAttributes();
        Object[] groups = new Object[10];
        groups = ctx.getObjectAttributes("memberof"); //returns empty array 

        Set<GrantedAuthority> authority = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

        for(Object group: groups){
            if (group.toString().toLowerCase().contains("ROLE_FROM_LDAP".toLowerCase()) == true){
                authority.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_APP"));
                break;          
            }           
        }

        User userDetails = new User(username, "", false, false, false, false, authority); 
        return userDetails;
}
```

Interestingly, when I run a query on LDAP using *ldapsearch*, I do get the attribute returned.

**What I am stuck at is how to configure the equivalent of "*requesting:*" (as shown below with *ldapsearch*) in the Grails LDAP configuration so that the plugin is able to fetch the "memberof" attribute (I tried adding that to Grails LDAP plugin configuration with *ldap.search.attributesToReturn* but to no avail).**

```
ldapsearch -t -x -b "ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com" "cn=myusername" memberof
.....
# LDAPv3
# base <ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: cn=myusername
# requesting: memberof
#
.....
dn: cn=myusername,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com
memberOf: cn=ROLE_FROM_LDAP,ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=com
```

Following is the Grails LDAP configuration:

```
grails {
    plugin {
        springsecurity {
            providerNames: ['ldapAuthProvider', 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider']          
            ldap {
                useRememberMe = false               
                context {
                    managerDn = 'cn=manager,dc=domain,dc=com'                   
                    managerPassword = 'secret'
                    server = 'ldap://localhost:389/'
                }      
                search {
                    base = 'ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com'
                    filter = 'cn={0}'
                    searchSubtree = true
                    attributesToReturn: ['memberOf'] //extra attributes you want returned
                }               
                auth {
                    hideUserNotFoundExceptions = false
                }
                authorities {
                    retrieveDatabaseRoles = false
                    retrieveGroupRoles = true
                    groupSearchBase = 'ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=com'                  
                    groupSearchFilter = 'member={0}'           
                }               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inject springSecurityService and fetch like:

```
springSecurityService.getPrincipal().getAuthorities()
```

Comment: Thanks Mike it helped, in fact the Collection authorities available in mapUserFromContext callback contained the authority objects. However, my original question remains on how to query the "memberof" attribute via Grails plugin configuration, as the query works through ldapsearch.