# Grails spring security LDAP get ROLE from LDAP base

Tags: authentication, grails, spring-security, active-directory, ldap

I have a grails 3.2.5 app with spring security LDAP auth 3.0.2. I need to get Roles from LDAP Base.

application.yml

```
plugin:
    springsecurity:
    #LDAP configuration
        logout.postOnly: false
        securityConfigType: 'InterceptUrlMap'
        debug:
            useFilter: true
        #useBasicAuth: true
        providerNames: ['ldapAuthProvider', 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider'] 
        ldap:
            context:
                managerDn: '****'
                managerPassword: '**password**'
                server: 'ldap://**my server**'
            authorities:
                ignorePartialResultException: true # typically needed for Active Directory
                groupSearchFilter: 'member={0}' # Active Directory specific - the example settings will
                retrieveGroupRoles: true # to get Roles from LDAP
                groupRoleAttribute: 'cn'
            search:
                base: DC=HQ,DC=ROOT,DC=AD
                filter: 'sAMAccountName={0}' # for Active Directory you need this
                searchSubtree: true
                attributesToReturn: ['mailNickName','name','mail','extensionAttribute13','extensionAttribute14','extensionAttribute15','company'] # extra attributes you want returned
            auth:
                hideUserNotFoundExceptions: false
```

In documentation I found that I need to set "retrieveGroupRoles: true" in `application.yml`, but how can I see what role have user?

Can you tell me how I can show user role to console or view for testing? Can I redefine (by default role getting from ldap 'cn') user role by getting it from user columns in LDAP?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject the following service into your controller:

```
def springSecurityService
```

Then access roles like:

```
def roles = springSecurityService.getPrincipal().getAuthorities()
```

Also as you're using application.yml you should specify your providerNames like this & not in list style:

```
providerNames:
    - ldapAuthProvider
    - anonymousAuthenticationProvider
```

The same goes for attributesToReturn:

```
attributesToReturn:
    - mailNickName
....
```

Comment: i did it and println in console but it show "[]" symbol (empty).

information: i have custom userDetail that is writed in spring-security-ldap documentation link paragraph 2.3. May be i need to add role in custom userDetail?

Comment: Check your'e definitely in a group, LDAP admin is good for this side of things http://www.ldapadmin.org/

Comment: Updated answer with other observations

Comment: Many thanks you are right. I havent a role in LDAP base.

Comment: for providerNames andattributesToReturn. It'swork in all variants.

Comment: How about second part of my question? Can i redefine a source of my role? For example: create a new coloumn in LDAP base with roles name and get user role from it?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe raise a new question specifically asking that now the role retrieval is sorted

Comment: I finded your answer about [grails ldap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316029/fetching-ldap-attribute-memberof-inside-grails-spring-application) and it helped me everywhere. Many thanks, the problem is closed.